# Ping script with email in vbs

Tags: vbscript, email, wsh

i know i asked already the question about the ping script but now i have a new question about it :-) I hope someone can help me again.

```
strText = "here comes the mail message"

strFile = "test.log"

PingForever strHost, strFile

Sub PingForever(strHost, outputfile)
    Dim Output, Shell, strCommand, ReturnCode

    Set Output = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(outputfile, 8, True)
    Set Shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    strCommand = "ping -n 1 -w 300 " & strHost
    While(True)
        ReturnCode = Shell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)     
        If ReturnCode = 0 Then
            Output.WriteLine Date() & " - " & Time & " | " & strHost & " - ONLINE"
        Else
            Output.WriteLine Date() & " - " & Time & " | " & strHost & " - OFFLINE"

            Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            objEmail.From = "noreply@test.net"
            objEmail.To = "test@test.net"
            objEmail.Subject = "Computer" & strHost & " is offline" 
            objEmail.Textbody = strText
            objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
                    "smtpadress" 
            objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
            objEmail.Send

        End If
        Wscript.Sleep 2000
    Wend
End Sub
```

My problem is now, the mail comes all 2 seconds, when the computer are offline. Can someone show me how to make it with flags? So only one mail comes when its offline?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag and report only when state changes

```
FLAG0 = "ON"
While(True)
    ReturnCode = Shell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)     
    If ReturnCode = 0 Then
        Output.WriteLine Date() & " - " & Time & " | " & strHost & " - ONLINE"
        FLAG0 = "ON"
    Else
        Output.WriteLine Date() & " - " & Time & " | " & strHost & " - OFFLINE"
        IF FLAG0 = "ON" THEN
           FLAG0 = "OFF"
           Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
           ...... rest of mailing code
        END IF

    End If
```

Comment: thank you, i try it, but there comes an syntax error...can you check your code, pls? I'm sry i never worked with flags before

Comment: Tried  to fix syntax errs. Check it now

Comment: now it comes the error message: Object  Required [string: "ON"]. Have you an idea?